How can I use mouse movement to scroll in Windows?
I have this command in linux that does this.
xinput --set-prop $id 'libinput Scroll Method Enabled' 0, 0, 1
xinput --set-prop $id 'libinput Button Scrolling Button' 2 
And there is Karabiner elements in MacOSX.
What can i use to do the same thing on windows ?
I have tried Googling. Cant find anything.
